# document.ready doesn't work when pressing link to home page

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the home page loads, `$(document).ready` works. When I click on a link that goes to the homepage, `$(document).ready` doesn't fire again.

I need it because I attach some events to the dom inside `$(document).ready` function. For whatever reason those attached events get removed when I click on the home page link.

How do I fix this?

Comment: can you post some code? It is expected that event handlers will get removed when you refresh the page, as it is an entirely new page load and the javascript runs all over again

Comment: is your "link that goes to the homepage" on the home page itself, or on a different page?

Comment: on same page. strange, this behavior only happens on my rails app.... I made a custom html and document.ready works as expected

Comment: If a link points to the current page, it's quite possible that the page doesn't reload when you click it, and then document ready won't fire again. As @bruchowski said, showing some code might help.

Comment: turbolinks was the issue. I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Any event should be attach outside $(document).ready(), could be before

```
 $(document).on('click', 'mySelector', function(){});
```

This will fire no matter what

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. rails 4 uses a js library called turbolinks. This was doing some sort of optimization that changes page without doing a full reload. You can fix this be removing turbolinks or using their own hooks to load scripts.